# Creating a OneToOne Relationship between 2 models(forms) in the same view

Tags: python, django

I am building a signup page.  I am using the default User model and a new model called UserInfo for additional user details.  I need to establish a OneToOne relationship between the 2 models.  To build the signup page, I made a form for each model and put them into the same signup view.

My question is, how to I set user(the OneToOneField) in UserInfo to the User that is being created in the same view UserInfo is created?  If you look in my views.py below, immediately after I saved User's form(signup_form), I tried a few things like..

- user2.user = User.objects.get(pk=pk) - doesn't seem to work
- user2.user = request.user - doesn't work because request.user is an anonymous user in this case
- user2.user = user - didn't work

**models.py:**

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):

    TITLE = (
        ('Salesperson', 'Salesperson'),
        ('Sales Representative', 'Sales Representative'),
        ('Broker', 'Broker'),
        ('Broker of Record', 'Broker of Record'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    preferred_email = models.EmailField()
    office_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    brokerage_of_agent = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    agent_title = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TITLE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.preferred_email
```

**forms.py:**

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

class UserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ['preferred_email', 'office_phone_number', 'brokerage_of_agent', 'agent_title']
```

**views.py:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('../dashboard/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        basic_info_form = UserInfoForm(request.POST)
        while (True):  # The while loop is used to get access to 'break' for the @gmail Email check
            if signup_form.is_valid():
                if not signup_form.cleaned_data['email'].endswith('@gmail.com'):
                    print('You must register with your @gmail.com Email')
                    break
                user = signup_form.save(commit=False)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()

                ### Look here!  I need to write something here I think, but I'm not sure what to write
                user2 = basic_info_form.save(commit=False)
                user2.user = User.objects.get(pk=pk) 
                user2 = user2.save()

                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user':user, 
                    'domain':current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                })
                mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
                to_email = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                email.send()
                return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    else:
        signup_form = SignupForm()
        basic_info_form = UserInfoForm()

    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'signup_form': signup_form, 'basic_info_form': basic_info_form})
```

**HTML Template:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in signup_form %}
    <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <small style="display: none">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
    <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in basic_info_form %}
    <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <small style="display: none">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
    <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}


    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What happened when you did ... `user2.user = user`

Comment: That stuff with while/break is nonsense. Checking if the email ends with gmail.com is *validation*, and belongs in a `clean_email()` method on SignupForm.

Comment: @jcfollower I tried `user2.user = user` again after deleting the lazy while loop... and it worked.  I feel stupid

Comment: @DanielRoseman I thought so.  The while loop was actually breaking the correct code that I had tried but didn't work because of the while loop.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

`user2.user = user` was actually the correct answer, but something with the clumsy while loop screwed it up so I thought it didn't work.